# Matlab: How to solve a system of equations with several variables appearing multiple times

Tags: matlab, wolfram-mathematica, wolframalpha

I have an equation looking like this:

```
w1   = (1/EI)*(heaviside(x - a1).*(((x - a1).^3)*F1(1))/6 + (C(1, 1)*x.^3)/6 + (C(2, 1)*x.^2)/2 + C(3, 1)*x + C(4, 1)) + (1/GAs).*(- heaviside(x - a1).*(x - a1)*F1(1) - C(1, 1).*x) - C(1, 1)/c_wa;
```

I use seven pairs of values from a measurement to solve this equation. I managed to solve it with the cftool-toolbox. But I don't really want to know the Cs, but c1, c2, k1 and k2.
I have four equations for the Cs. Now I want to solve these equations for c1, c2, k1 and k2. So far I have no clue how to do it, since the variables I want to solve for appear multiple times in each equation.

I tried to insert the four equations into my first equation and use cftool to solve it, but that does not work properly because it gets too complex.

```
 C(1, 1) = ((c1*F*(-2*a^3*c2*(EI*(k1 + k2) + k1*k2*l) + 3*a^2*c2*k1*l*(2*EI + k2*l) + 6*a*c2*EI*l*(2*EI + k2*l) - ...
     12*EI^2*(c2*l^2 + k1 + k2) - 4*c2*EI*l^3*(k1 + k2) - c2*k1*k2*l^4 - 12*EI*k1*k2*l))/ ...
     (12*EI^2*(c1 + c2)*(k1 + k2) + 12*c1*c2*EI^2*l^2 + 4*c1*c2*EI*l^3*(k1 + k2) + ...
     12*EI*k1*k2*l*(c1 + c2) + c1*c2*k1*k2*l^4));

C(2, 1) = ((F*k1*(2*EI*l*(a^3*c1*c2 + 6*a*k2*(c1 + c2) - 6*c2*EI) + c2*l^2*(a^3*c1*k2 - 6*a^2*c1*EI - 6*EI*k2) - ...
     2*a*c1*c2*l^3*(a*k2 - 2*EI) - 6*a*EI*(c1 + c2)*(a*k2 - 2*EI) + a*c1*c2*k2*l^4))/ ...
     (12*EI^2*(c1 + c2)*(k1 + k2) + 12*c1*c2*EI^2*l^2 + 4*c1*c2*EI*l^3*(k1 + k2) + ...
     12*EI*k1*k2*l*(c1 + c2) + c1*c2*k1*k2*l^4));

C(3, 1) = ((EI*F*(2*EI*l*(a^3*c1*c2 + 6*a*k2*(c1 + c2) - 6*c2*EI) + c2*l^2*(a^3*c1*k2 - 6*a^2*c1*EI - 6*EI*k2) - ...
     2*a*c1*c2*l^3*(a*k2 - 2*EI) - 6*a*EI*(c1 + c2)*(a*k2 - 2*EI) + a*c1*c2*k2*l^4))/ ...
     (12*EI^2*(c1 + c2)*(k1 + k2) + 12*c1*c2*EI^2*l^2 + 4*c1*c2*EI*l^3*(k1 + k2) + ...
     12*EI*k1*k2*l*(c1 + c2) + c1*c2*k1*k2*l^4));

C(4, 1) = ((EI*F*(2*a^3*c2*(EI*(k1 + k2) + k1*k2*l) - 3*a^2*c2*k1*l*(2*EI + k2*l) - 6*a*c2*EI*l*(2*EI + k2*l) + ...
     12*EI^2*(c2*l^2 + k1 + k2) + 4*EI*l*(c2*l^2*(k1 + k2) + 3*k1*k2) + c2*k1*k2*l^4))/ ...
     (12*EI^2*(c1 + c2)*(k1 + k2) + 12*c1*c2*EI^2*l^2 + 4*c1*c2*EI*l^3*(k1 + k2) + ...
     12*EI*k1*k2*l*(c1 + c2) + c1*c2*k1*k2*l^4));
```

I would be very grateful for some hints! If this kind of problem is only solvable with Mathematica or Derive, I'd also be happy to get solutions regarding those!

EDIT (to Bill Aug 7 at 23:08):

Thanks for your reply!

- the "..." means new line
- EI, F1(1), GAs, F, c_wa are given variables (where did you see F?)

Therefore:

```
C(1, 1) = ((c1*F*(-2*a^3*c2*(EI*(k1 + k2) + k1*k2*l) + 3*a^2*c2*k1*l*(2*EI + k2*l) + 6*a*c2*EI*l*(2*EI + k2*l) - 12*EI^2*(c2*l^2 + k1 + k2) - 4*c2*EI*l^3*(k1 + k2) - c2*k1*k2*l^4 - 12*EI*k1*k2*l))/ (12*EI^2*(c1 + c2)*(k1 + k2) + 12*c1*c2*EI^2*l^2 + 4*c1*c2*EI*l^3*(k1 + k2) + 12*EI*k1*k2*l*(c1 + c2) + c1*c2*k1*k2*l^4));

C(2, 1) = ((F*k1*(2*EI*l*(a^3*c1*c2 + 6*a*k2*(c1 + c2) - 6*c2*EI) + c2*l^2*(a^3*c1*k2 - 6*a^2*c1*EI - 6*EI*k2) - ...
     2*a*c1*c2*l^3*(a*k2 - 2*EI) - 6*a*EI*(c1 + c2)*(a*k2 - 2*EI) + a*c1*c2*k2*l^4))/ (12*EI^2*(c1 + c2)*(k1 + k2) + 12*c1*c2*EI^2*l^2 + 4*c1*c2*EI*l^3*(k1 + k2) + 12*EI*k1*k2*l*(c1 + c2) + c1*c2*k1*k2*l^4));

C(3, 1) = ((EI*F*(2*EI*l*(a^3*c1*c2 + 6*a*k2*(c1 + c2) - 6*c2*EI) + c2*l^2*(a^3*c1*k2 - 6*a^2*c1*EI - 6*EI*k2) - 2*a*c1*c2*l^3*(a*k2 - 2*EI) - 6*a*EI*(c1 + c2)*(a*k2 - 2*EI) + a*c1*c2*k2*l^4))/ (12*EI^2*(c1 + c2)*(k1 + k2) + 12*c1*c2*EI^2*l^2 + 4*c1*c2*EI*l^3*(k1 + k2) + 12*EI*k1*k2*l*(c1 + c2) + c1*c2*k1*k2*l^4));

C(4, 1) = ((EI*F*(2*a^3*c2*(EI*(k1 + k2) + k1*k2*l) - 3*a^2*c2*k1*l*(2*EI + k2*l) - 6*a*c2*EI*l*(2*EI + k2*l) + 12*EI^2*(c2*l^2 + k1 + k2) + 4*EI*l*(c2*l^2*(k1 + k2) + 3*k1*k2) + c2*k1*k2*l^4))/ (12*EI^2*(c1 + c2)*(k1 + k2) + 12*c1*c2*EI^2*l^2 + 4*c1*c2*EI*l^3*(k1 + k2) + 12*EI*k1*k2*l*(c1 + c2) + c1*c2*k1*k2*l^4));
```

Even though you don't need them to solve the problem for the understanding:

```
EI = 8.0934e+11
F1 = [10000 345] 
=> F = F1(1) = 10000 
=> a = F1(2) = 345
GAs = 7.0852e+08 
c_wa = 2.115e+05;
```

Kind regards,

AMK

Comment: If you can translate your problem into Mathematica notation and include your four "c" equations without "..." and provide any other information that someone who knows nothing about what you have been doing then someone might be able to take a moment and attack that with Mathematica.  heaviside I can find the documentation with Google, but things like EI, F1, F, c_wa, etc I am uncertain whether these are variables with unknown values, with known values or predefined functions from Matlab. Given a description that anyone could understand with no added questions or mistakes might get an answer

Comment: Is this a system of equations? How many unknowns do you have? How many equations do you have? I think you just have a really long formula and want to simplify it.